# EF Code First & Stored Procedures return Multiple Results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I read this article https://romiller.com/2012/08/15/code-first-stored-procedures-with-multiple-results/

and tried to implement the below code to handle stored procedure which returns multiple result sets.

These are namespaces I included:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;
```

See my full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EFTest.demo1;

namespace EFTest
{
    public partial class CallSP : Form
    {
        public CallSP()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var db = new TestDBContext1())
            {
                db.Database.Initialize(force: false);
                // Create a SQL command to execute the sproc 
                var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[MultiResultSet]";

                try
                {

                    db.Database.Connection.Open();
                    // Run the sproc  
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    // Read Blogs from the first result set 
                    var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<Customer>(reader, "Customers", MergeOption.AppendOnly);


                    foreach (var item in blogs)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                    }

                    // Move to second result set and read Posts 
                    reader.NextResult();
                    var posts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<Addresses>(reader, "Addresses", MergeOption.AppendOnly);


                    foreach (var item in posts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    db.Database.Connection.Close();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My sample stored procedure which return multiple result set

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MultiResultSet]
AS
    SELECT * FROM Customers

    SELECT * FROM Addresses
```

I am getting compilation error.

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.Translate(System.Data.Common.DbDataReader,
>   string, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption)' has some invalid
>   arguments

Please help me what to fix as a result there should be no compilation error.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using EF5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MergeOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.mergeoption(v=vs.113).aspx) from namespace [`System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.mergeoption(v=vs.113).aspx) instead of using [MergeOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption(v=vs.110).aspx) from [`System.Data.Objects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<Customer>(reader, "Customers", System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

and

```
var posts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<Addresses>(reader, "Addresses", System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```